# How to achieve the custom picker with Month, Date and time in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, uipickerview

I am developing an app which requires to select the date from a picker view. But the picker view requires the Month,Date and time in the Picker view rows like in the attached image:

[image: Desired Output]

currently i am having the following code :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

   @IBOutlet weak var txtDatePicker: UITextField!
  let datePicker = UIDatePicker()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
     showDatePicker()
  }


  func showDatePicker(){
    //Formate Date
    datePicker.datePickerMode = .date

   //ToolBar
   let toolbar = UIToolbar();
   toolbar.sizeToFit()
   let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(donedatePicker));
   let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
  let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(cancelDatePicker));

 toolbar.setItems([doneButton,spaceButton,cancelButton], animated: false)

  txtDatePicker.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
  txtDatePicker.inputView = datePicker

 }

  @objc func donedatePicker(){

   let formatter = DateFormatter()
   formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
   txtDatePicker.text = formatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
   self.view.endEditing(true)
 }

 @objc func cancelDatePicker(){
    self.view.endEditing(true)
  }
}
```

But with this i am getting the output as :

[image: Output PickerView]

How to add time to the UIPickerView ? Please suggest and help

Comment: Please check this URL, maybe it helps - https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/selecting-dates-and-times-with-datepicker

Comment: Why are you using `UIDatePicker`?  Why don't you just use UIPicker?

Comment: @ElTomato can you please help me with that?

Comment: Create three arrays and load them with the pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) method.

Comment: to set the datepicker to show date and time  you can set         datePicker.datePickerMode = .dateAndTime

Comment: @ElTomato thanks for the suggestion i have implemented it .. But any idea for the validation of invalid dates like "31 April", "30 February", "30 June"

Comment: Unless you specify the year, you cannot validate the date of the month and the day of the month of selection.

Answer (score -1):

Go to storyboard select your date picker view and in attribute inspector select date and time instead of Date.

And then you can select the date and time for the date picker.

[image]